# Active Unions in Static Scope

Tags: scope, pascal

Suppose i want to know what unions(referencing environment) are active in the point marked with (*), how do i acknowledge that ? Which unions are in fact active ?

```
procedure P(A,B ; real)  
       X: real  
       procedure Q(B,C : real)  
       y : real  
       ...  
       procedure R(A,C : real)  
       Z:real  
       ........             --(*)
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: This doesn't look like C...

Comment: Lol, yea you are right ... i think it is Pascal,sorry.I am tyring to solve that for my Programming Languages Exam, tomorrow ? Can you help meOli ?

Answer (score 1):

It's basic nesting basically. But you don't specify the full blockstructure (with begin..end pairs) to fully fixate the structure.

Assuming from indentation that the begin end; block of P is at the end, and of Q and R is directly after resp. the y and z declarations, then in Q:   Q is searched first, then P, then the scope above P (mainprogram/unit or another procedure), in R  R, P,unit etc.